# Как инициализировать объекты по списку?

Tags: java, android

Есть класс, например

```
class Box(){
  int ID;
  String Name;
  double w;
  double h;
  double s;
}
```

есть список

```
private List<Integer> lBoxes = Arrays.asList(5,1,7,3,8,51,42);
```

надо чтобы по этому списку создались экземпляры класса Box() с именами соответственно box5(), box1(), box7() и т.д. по списку.

В последствии мне надо будет обращаться к этим экземплярам класса по этому же списку или другому, чтобы получить поля или присвоить полям значения.
например:

```
box5.ID = 5;
box5.Name = "Ящик номер 5";
```

другими словами пронумеровать экземпляры класса, чтобы обращаться к их полям по их условным номерам из любого списка. Естественно, не создавать экземпляры тех номеров, которых нет в списке.

Как это лучше организовать?

Comment: `List<Box>` *(3 символа нужно...)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Java именно так как Вы хотите сделать нельзя. Как вариант можно создать List на нужное количество элементов и обращаться потом по его индексу или Map, где ключ — имя переменной например "box5", а значение это объект класса Box.

```
for(Integer i : lBoxes) {
    boxesMap.put("box"+i,new Box(i));
}
```

инициализировать можно сразу

```
class Box(){
  int ID;
  String Name;
...
 Box(Integer i){
   this.ID=i;
   this.Name="Ящик номер "+ i;
 }
```

Comment: Вы можете привести пример кода?

Comment: Reflection может все!

Comment: Мне кажется в данном случае лучше всего использовать Map, пример отредактировал.  Ну а Reflection, очень хотел бы посмотреть пример от Олексій Моренець.

Answer (score 2):

Создавайте в цикле:

```
private List<Integer> lBoxes = Arrays.asList(5,1,7,3,8,51,42);
private List<Box> boxes = new ArrayList<>();

for(Integer i : lBoxes) {
    boxes.add(new Box(...));
}
```